# Stata: tag all values in a group based on a characteristic of any values in the group

Tags: stata

I think `egen` might help me here, but for whatever reason I can't quite figure out the right syntax. I'd like to create a new variable that takes a value of 1 for all observations in a group if, for any of the observations in the group, X is true. So, for example, my data has the `obs`, `group`, and `flag` variables, and I want to generate the variable `grpflag`.

```
obs    group  flag    grpflag
1      1      0       1
2      1      1       1
3      1      0       1
4      2      0       0
5      2      0       0
6      2      0       0
7      3      1       1
8      3      0       1
```

So, in the example data, since `flag==1` for one (i.e., any) of the observations in group 1, I want `grpflag` to take the value 1 for all observations in group 1. The same is true for group 3, and the opposite is true for group 2.

Answer (score 3):

You were right: the `egen` command can do this.

```
egen grpflag = max(flag), by(group)
```

See the Stata FAQ http://www.stata.com/support/faqs/data-management/create-variable-recording/ for more detail on the correspondences any:maximum and all:minimum exploited in Stata.

Note that while your example is easy (`flag` is already 0 or 1, so `max()` can be applied directly to `flag`) the argument of `max()` can be an expression, so the syntax extends easily to more general cases, e.g. `max(foo == 42)`.

Even if `egen` were not available, or did not work like this, this kind of one-liner is possible in Stata, and will be more efficient than calling `egen`:

```
bysort group (flag) : gen grpflag = flag[_N]
```

However, that would be thrown by missings on `flag`, so you would need to work around that. In turn that could just be

```
gen isflag = flag == 1 
bysort group (isflag) : gen grpflag = isflag[_N]
```

The general principle is that so long as what you are sorting is just 0 and 1, any values of 1 will be sorted to the end within each block of observations.